# ng-repeat execute many times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a little [demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQz49/1/) :

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkUsr{{usr.Id}}" ng-model="usr.Checked">
{{usr.Name}} : {{usr.Checked}}
<input type="text" ng-model="research"/>
<div ng-repeat="entity in entities | filter:research | log">
Hello {{entity.id}}!
```

JavaScript:

```
app.filter('log', function() {
    return function(items) {
        console.log('yo');
        return items;
    };
});
```

The log filter is called when input change (even the checkbox).

How to change that and  trigger log filter only when text input change ?

Comment: Use onchange event of input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because angular runs `$digest` and updates all the scope properties even if one variable in the scope changes. It is called "dirty checking".

Learn more about how angular works: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: Correction ` angular runs $digest and updates all the scope properties`, angular runs digest and verifies all scope properties for change. Part of the verification is calling the filter and making sure data has not changed.