# Angularjs ng-repeat with datepicker filter executing many times

Tags: angularjs, filter, datepicker, angularjs-ng-repeat

I finally managed to make my date filters work but now I have a problem...

I have a simple table that is supposed to be filtered by name and date. It is filtering correctly but the date filter is extremely slow. After debugging and researching I know the problem is that my custom dates range (from - to) filter is called many times. 
It is called:

1. When I click on the calendar to choose a date but before actually showing the calendar control
2. Right after showing the calendar
3. After selecting a date

It even runs the first 2 times if I don't chose any date after opening the calendar. It also runs every time I change from one month to another.

Also, for each of those 3 times the filter is called, it also runs once for each row I have in the list. In the example I have only 10 rows (it is actually fast) but in my application it has maaany more and it takes a long time.

The ideal is that this code gets called only once after selecting a date.

For simplicity I'm showing here a few lines of my code, but you can see the whole example on this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fVsQ3D8h3Yz1z6u3vHaa?p=preview) :

HTML Code:

```
<!-- This is the datepicker control filter -->
<ng-datepicker ng-model="DateRegisteredFrom" view-format="MM/DD/YYYY" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></ng-datepicker>

<!-- Here is the table  -->
<tr ng-repeat="item in model.People | filter:searchText | dateRegisteredFilter:DateRegisteredFrom:DateRegisteredTo | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort ">
</tr>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
.filter("dateRegisteredFilter", function($filter, $rootScope) {
    return function(items, from, to) {
       return $filter('filter')(items, "DateRegistered", function(v) {

           // Filter code...

      });
   };
});
```

After a lot of reading and researching I learned 2 things:

1. My code gets called this many times due to "dirty checking" done by angular (I read it thanks to this answer: [ng-repeat execute many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927440/ng-repeat-execute-many-times) )
2. The actual comparision of dates is slow (this would be ok if the code was executed only once but not many)

I would appreciate a lot if somebody could point me on the right direction or if I'm doing something wrong as I've been reading and I only find the reason why this happens but I can't find a solution or a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change how you are handling your ng-repeat.  As you are aware, these filters is constantly running, and because of that it is causing things to run slowly.  What you should do is transform the data in `model.People` separately in your controller instead of piping it through multiple filters.  Doing it that way, you can better control when and where the filtering gets done.

This link has a cool gif that helps to show why things are so slow as well https://medium.com/@lightingbeetle/some-best-practices-when-building-a-large-angular-application-c346734a4e9c