# Reinitialize a ng-init variable in a ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

Below is my code for a simple loop of AngularJS, with initializing c=1 initially. Based on the condition, value of `c` needs to be updated in the subsequent iterations. 
For example, let's assume `<some other condition>` evaluates to be true in the first 3 iterations and `<some condition>` evaluates to be true in the last iteration, then the output expected is :

1 to 11

11 to 21

21 to 31

31

So basically, what is required is condition that needs to be put in HTML comment place below.

```
<div  ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4]" ng-init="c=1">
        <div ng-if="<some condition>">
              {{c}}
           <!-- need to update c=c+1 here-->
        </div>

        <div ng-if="<some other condition>">
             {{c}} to {{c+10)}}
             <!-- need to update c=c+10 here-->
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly can you remove Angular Tag ? This is an AngularJS Question. Secondly why do you want to do this in HTML ? You must put less business as possible in HTML.

Comment: This is a terrible way to solve the problem.  It is not a "simple loop", and it uses techniques that go against everything that AngularJs was designed around.

Comment: @Claies : any work around for this ?

Comment: Not putting this logic in the HTML, no.  Put the logic in a controller where it belongs

Comment: @Claies : This actually needs no logic, putting it in a controller  will make the code unnecessarily lengthier. No other way to reinitialize variable in the loop itself? Any hack or something ?

Comment: What do you mean “this needs no logic”?  There is a ton of logic here; you are trying to change a value on every iteration.  There is no way this can be reasonably done in the HTML, because angular two way binding causes the whole loop to be re-evaluated every time you change the value.  You can’t have the same variable have different values in a single page render.

Answer (score 0):

### Edited

New Fiddle for comment by Claies. I still recommend my initial post but I created the Fiddle below to show how to accomplish the task via HTML and minimal JS.

This uses ngInits to change C. The key thing here is since ngRepeats create a separate scope, changing C within the ngIf will not apply to the entire scope. To do this, we create a local copy in the ngInit to use for display purposes and then call a function to change C on the global scope layer which is then used in subsequent iterations of the ngRepeat.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  $scope.c = 1;
  
  $scope.changeC = function(increment) {
   $scope.c = $scope.c + increment;  
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in arr">
      <!-- CONDITION #1 -->
      <!-- TEST CASE : IS ITEM EVEN? -->
      <div ng-if="item % 2 == 1" ng-init="localC = c; changeC(1);">
        {{localC}} to {{localC+1}}
      </div>
      <!-- CONDITION #2 -->
      <!-- TEST CASE : IS ITEM ODD? -->
      <div ng-if="item % 2 == 0" ng-init="localC = c; changeC(10);">
        {{localC}} to {{localC+10}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As everyone has stated in the comments, this business logic should be executed in the controller. The structure of your HTML is basically a for-loop with two conditions to check for within it. Therefore, you can easily do this within the controller. Set c to be a variable in the scope: `$scope.c = ...` and then use it in the HTML/JS as needed.

You're going to run into trouble using an ngRepeat to increment variables inside of an ngInit since the ngRepeat is run multiple times due to [how AngularJS runs $digest cycles and dirty checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927440/ng-repeat-execute-many-times). This is even more of a reason to use the controller for your logic. Please see below a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzack5020/pe1oh057/) as a solution for your problem.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl',['$scope',function($scope) {
 $scope.arr = [1,2,3,4];
  $scope.c = 0;
  
  for(var i = 0, iMax = $scope.arr.length; i < iMax; i++) {
   var curr = $scope.arr[i];

    // Put first condition here
    if(curr == 1) {
     $scope.c += 1;
    } 
    
    // Put second condition here
    if(curr == 2) {
     $scope.c += 10;
    }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
      {{c}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, while this is in the spirit of what I was suggesting, I don't think it will create the output that the OP is after.

Comment: See edit - is this what the OP was asking for? I don't recommend it but if that's what required then that should work.